# Unable to boot ubuntu 14.4 from usb on dell inspirton 15 3537

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

So I recently installed windows 10 on my computer. Before that I had a dual boot windows 7/ubuntu 14.4. Now I wanted to boot ubuntu from a usb.

I created a live usb using unetbootin. After that I rebooted my pc, pressed F12 (to access boot menu) and selected USB Storage Device. But then nothing happened. My old OS started booting and nothing else happened. Since then I have changed a few settings in hope that my flash drive would be recognized by my computer, but it didn't. So if anybody has had a similar or the same problem and has figured it out please do share your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sir,It is mainly caused by bad installation or corrupt structure. SO I request you to wipe the flash drive and do the installation once again using universal usb installerand try again.
It worked for me ;-)

Download Link for UNIVERSAL USB INSTALLER:
[Refer this link for download and installation guide](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Answer (score 0):

First Disable Secure Boot in your BIOS and disable Fast Startup.To disable Fast Startup follow these instructions I took from eightforums.com

```
7. To Turn Off "Fast Startup" for a "Full Shutdown"

A) First go to your System Settings.In that under Shutdown settings, uncheck the Turn on fast startup box, and click/tap on the Save changes button. (see screenshot below step 6A)

NOTE: If the Turn on fast startup setting is not listed, then hibernate has been disabled that removed this setting and also disabled fast startup.

B) The Shut down Power option will now perform as a normal full shut down when used.
```

After disabling Fast Startup go to your BIOS and make sure that Secure Boot is disabled.

After doing those steps use Rufus to burn the ISO to the USB as it's the easiest way to get a bootable USB Ubuntu installation.After it's burned reboot the computer and access the BIOS and select the USB device and it should work.